# Передать id пользователя Telegram в форму на сайте

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Пользователь телеграм переходит по ссылке бота на сайт для заполнения формы обратной связи, как получить его токен для обратной связи в телеграме?

Comment: Передавайте в форму, либо как аргумент ссылки `message.chat.id`

Comment: а как передать его в форму?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ссылка должна выглядеть примерно так: http://some.site.com/?chat_id=123

где `123` это `message.chat.id` пользователя, который начал диалог с вашим ботом.

Пример на PHP:

```
<?php
$chat_id= $_GET['chat_id'];
?>
----------
<input id='chat_id' type='hidden' value='<?php echo $chat_id; ?>' >
```

Пример на Javascript:

```
function querySt(ji) {

    hu = window.location.search.substring(1);
    gy = hu.split("&");

    for (i=0;i<gy.length;i++) {
        ft = gy[i].split("=");
        if (ft[0] == ji) {
            return ft[1];
        }
    }
}

var koko = querySt("koko");

document.getElementById('mytxt').value = koko;
```

[Источник](https://coderoad.ru/5422265/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-html-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-url)

поисковый запрос: *заполнить поле формы из ссылки*